# How to resolve moment-timezone import issue with meteor npm

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to use the moment-timezone npm package in my meteor app to no avail. If I use the atmosphere package, everything runs just fine. However I would like to get the npm package running as the atmosphere one is no longer being maintained. I have removed the atmosphere package completely from the app before trying to get it running via npm.

When I run `meteor npm list --tree`, towards the bottom the moment-timezone package and its dependency appear:

```
└─┬ moment-timezone@0.5.23
  └── moment@2.22.2
```

and `meteor npm install` gives:

```
audited 107 packages in 1.913s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

In the file where I'm using moment-timezone I have

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

But the javascript console shows it is failing on the import of both moment and moment-timezone:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'moment'. import call expects
exactly one argument.
```

Following the console error, these two lines in two separate files are highlighted in red

```
import moment from 'moment';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

So it looks to me that it isn't able to resolve the packages, but it appears as if they have been installed correctly and meteor npm install has worked fine.

The app is meteor 1.8

I'm out of ideas - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I am working on this as well and have determined that the issues isn't so much what we are trying to import but rather where.

It seems that no matter what file I put the import statement into I get the error

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

From the running app console. We've tried startup.js and pretty much every other .js file in the client directory with the same result. Where should these go?

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 use like below

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

here is you can see [`Timezone Support`](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/385#issuecomment-292900349)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it's still showing up as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I've also tried doing meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs ... no luck

Comment: @mpzo what technology you use for frontend

Comment: I'm using blaze

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Unexpected identifier' implies that the `import` lines haven't been transpiled and your browser doesn't understand them. Have you added the `ecmascript` atmosphere package to your project?

Once you've added it, the only import you should need is:

`import moment from 'moment-timezone';`